# Oracle PL/SQL modify column DEFAULT_LENGTH attribute

Tags: oracle, data-dictionary

I have attribute DEFAULT_LENGTH in bellow select:

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME,
  COLUMN_NAME,
  DATA_DEFAULT,
  DEFAULT_LENGTH
FROM all_tab_columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TEST2';
```

For changing DATA_DEFAULT I used below syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST2 MODIFY (COL1 DEFAULT 'en');
```

How can I change with similar alter option syntax DEFAULT_LENGTH?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious as to why you care about amending this column?

Comment: I need two tables with same columns definition structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "How can I change with similar alter option syntax DEFAULT_LENGTH?"

You don't need to. DEFAULT_LENGTH is derived from the length of the DATA_DEFAULT.

Comment: As demonstrated here: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_E9KDO18Q7O6TM3VQKWPEJ2PGF.html  (obvs, I was too slow! *{;-) )

Comment: @Boneist - It's interesting that the value  of `default_length` is larger than the length of the `data_default` value. In your livesql example, it's +2, in my database here (which I cannot cut'n'paste from) it's +3. Any ideas why?

Comment: The same case for me.

Comment: @Catalin - so is that why you're asking how to set the DEFAULT_LENGTH ?

Comment: Yes, I have two tables with same structure but DEFAULT_LENGTH isn't the same.

Comment: @APC it appears that the DATA_DEFAULT for a VARCHAR2 includes the two single quotes used to enclose the value *definition*, so a data default of 'ABC' has length 5, 0 has length 1 and NULL has length 4. And sometimes there can be a trailing space in the definition, adding to the length.

Comment: @Catalin It really doesn't matter, but you could make them the same by running `ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY (COL1 DEFAULT 'en');` on both tables!

Comment: @TonyAndrews - you are probably correct. For a table with a VARCHAR2(1000) column, alter the table to change the default for this column to NULL - the DEFAULT_LENGTH becomes 4. Then alter again to change the default to `''` (empty string, which in Oracle is the same as NULL - contrary to the standard), and the DEFAULT_LENGTH becomes 2. One has to wonder why Oracle needs to know the length of the DEFAULT_VALUE value in the catalog, instead of the length of the default value as it would appear in the table.

Comment: `create table t (i varchar2(1000) default 'abc'   ,dummy number);` (3 spaces after the `'abc'`) default_length = 8 :)

Comment: `create table t1 (i varchar2(1000) default 'abc' /* some comments for padding*/,dummy number);` default_length = 36